# Reduce space between column in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have column highcharts with 2 series.

[image]
I tried to setup properties as below but space between column not reduce.

```
column: {
        pointPadding: 0, //also tried 0.1
        pointWidth: 35,
        groupPadding:0.1, // also tried 0
        borderWidth: 0
      },
```

How can I change space between column, i want to fix width 35px.

This is my source code. Thanks

```js
var ConstantsConfigChart = {
  colorText: "#444",
  fontsize12: "12px",
  fontsize14: "14px",
  fontsize16: "16px"
}
var Constants = {
  OKWON: 100000000
}
let topRightOption = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 10,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    animation: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Unit',
    align: 'left',
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    },
    margin: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 12,
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [],
    crosshair: true,
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
        fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: ' '
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        },
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / Constants.OKWON, 1);
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: {
        text: ' ',
        style: {}
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1);
        },
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        }
      },
      opposite: true,
      offset: 10,
      crosshair: true
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var tooltip = [],

        title = "<span class=\"TooltipText12\">" + this.x + "</span><br/>";
      tooltip.push(title + '<br>');
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        if (i < 2) {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y / Constants.OKWON, 1) + '<span style="padding:0"> 억원</span> <br/>');
        } else {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + this.point.y + '<span style="padding:0">%</span> <br/>');
        }

      });

      return tooltip.join('');
    },
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      pointWidth: 35,
      groupPadding: 0.1,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: {
      animation: false
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#fe7c7c', '#43d487', '#ff9600'],
  series: [],
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    itemStyle: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  }
};

data = {
  "StatisticGoalFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 900000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 700000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 770000000.0
    }
  ],
  "StatisticRealFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 860000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 460000000.0
    }, {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 590000000.0
    }
  ],
  "ProgressKRW100Rate": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 0.5
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 117.9
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 3.0
    }
  ]
};



let seriesGoal = data.StatisticGoalFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let seriesReal = data.StatisticRealFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let rates = data.ProgressKRW100Rate.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
topRightOption.xAxis.categories = seriesGoal.map(c => c.name);

//this.bottomRightOption.series[1].data = seriesReal;
var top_right = Highcharts.chart('container', topRightOption);
top_right.addSeries({
  name: "도전",
  data: seriesGoal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      textOutline: false,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    },
    align: 'right',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});

top_right.addSeries({
  name: "실적",
  data: seriesReal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      textOutline: false,
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    align: 'left',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/vkm4eLdp/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried add configure for series

```
series: {
        animation: false,
        pointWidth: 35,
        groupPadding: 0.4,
}
```

and remove `groupPadding:0.1, //groupPadding:0.1,`

It is better now, but i want to have more better solution.

**Finally i found maxpointWidth option, with maxpointWidth:35, when I resize screen column size change well.**

```js
var ConstantsConfigChart = {
  colorText: "#444",
  fontsize12: "12px",
  fontsize14: "14px",
  fontsize16: "16px"
}
var Constants = {
  OKWON: 100000000
}
let topRightOption = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 10,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    animation: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Unit',
    align: 'left',
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    },
    margin: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 12,
  },

  xAxis: {
    width: '350px',
    categories: [],
    crosshair: true,
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
        fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: ' '
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        },
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / Constants.OKWON, 1);
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: {
        text: ' ',
        style: {}
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1);
        },
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        }
      },
      opposite: true,
      offset: 10,
      crosshair: true
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var tooltip = [],

        title = "<span class=\"TooltipText12\">" + this.x + "</span><br/>";
      tooltip.push(title + '<br>');
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        if (i < 2) {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y / Constants.OKWON, 1) + '<span style="padding:0"> 억원</span> <br/>');
        } else {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + this.point.y + '<span style="padding:0">%</span> <br/>');
        }

      });

      return tooltip.join('');
    },
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.05,
      pointWidth: 35,
      //groupPadding: 0.1,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: {
      animation: false,
      pointWidth: 35,
      groupPadding: 0.4,
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#fe7c7c', '#43d487', '#ff9600'],
  series: [],
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    itemStyle: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  }
};

data = {
  "StatisticGoalFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 900000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 700000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 770000000.0
    }
  ],
  "StatisticRealFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 860000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 460000000.0
    }, {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 590000000.0
    }
  ],
  "ProgressKRW100Rate": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 0.5
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 117.9
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 3.0
    }
  ]
};



let seriesGoal = data.StatisticGoalFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let seriesReal = data.StatisticRealFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let rates = data.ProgressKRW100Rate.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
topRightOption.xAxis.categories = seriesGoal.map(c => c.name);

//this.bottomRightOption.series[1].data = seriesReal;
var top_right = Highcharts.chart('container', topRightOption);
top_right.addSeries({
  name: "도전",
  data: seriesGoal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      textOutline: false,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    },
    align: 'right',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});

top_right.addSeries({
  name: "실적",
  data: seriesReal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      textOutline: false,
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    align: 'left',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hi @Hien Nguyen,  Why this solution is not completely satisfying for you? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: I have a problem when number of data in series increase, columns are overlap, i am trying check size to reduce pointWidth. Do you have solution when number of columns is increase? Also I have issue when screen size is change or responsive

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification, but do you have to set a fixed point width in this case? The default point width is calculated based on axis units. In your case it is hard to match pixel width and responsive design. You can always manually position the columns by SVG transitions.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this is to use `Axis resizer`, but this will change the overall width, not only the space between the bars.

Have in mind that, since this solution uses a fixed `px` value you will need to calculate this value based on the number of bars.

```
xAxis: {
   width: '350px',
   // ...
}
```

```js
var ConstantsConfigChart = {
  colorText: "#444",
  fontsize12: "12px",
  fontsize14: "14px",
  fontsize16: "16px"
}
var Constants = {
  OKWON: 100000000
}
let topRightOption = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 10,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    animation: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Unit',
    align: 'left',
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    },
    margin: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 12,
  },

  xAxis: {
    width: '350px',
    categories: [],
    crosshair: true,
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
        fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: ' '
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        },
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / Constants.OKWON, 1);
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: {
        text: ' ',
        style: {}
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1);
        },
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        }
      },
      opposite: true,
      offset: 10,
      crosshair: true
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var tooltip = [],

        title = "<span class=\"TooltipText12\">" + this.x + "</span><br/>";
      tooltip.push(title + '<br>');
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        if (i < 2) {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y / Constants.OKWON, 1) + '<span style="padding:0"> 억원</span> <br/>');
        } else {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + this.point.y + '<span style="padding:0">%</span> <br/>');
        }

      });

      return tooltip.join('');
    },
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      pointWidth: 35,
      groupPadding: 0.1,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: {
      animation: false
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#fe7c7c', '#43d487', '#ff9600'],
  series: [],
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    itemStyle: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  }
};

data = {
  "StatisticGoalFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 900000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 700000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 770000000.0
    }
  ],
  "StatisticRealFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 860000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 460000000.0
    }, {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 590000000.0
    }
  ],
  "ProgressKRW100Rate": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 0.5
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 117.9
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 3.0
    }
  ]
};



let seriesGoal = data.StatisticGoalFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let seriesReal = data.StatisticRealFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let rates = data.ProgressKRW100Rate.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
topRightOption.xAxis.categories = seriesGoal.map(c => c.name);

//this.bottomRightOption.series[1].data = seriesReal;
var top_right = Highcharts.chart('container', topRightOption);
top_right.addSeries({
  name: "도전",
  data: seriesGoal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      textOutline: false,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    },
    align: 'right',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});

top_right.addSeries({
  name: "실적",
  data: seriesReal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      textOutline: false,
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    align: 'left',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: when i tried to change xAxis 50%, data label is overlapped. this solution may be not work with more categories

Comment: You are right, I've updated the answer to use pixels instead. Please let me know if it works like that.

Answer (score 0):

It probably didn't work as you expected because you're setting `pointWidth` the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.columnrange.pointWidth) say

> A pixel value specifying a fixed width for each column or bar. **When null, the width is calculated from the pointPadding and groupPadding.**

So if you don't set the width, you might get somewhere settings `pointPadding` and/or `groupPadding`

```js
var ConstantsConfigChart = {
  colorText: "#444",
  fontsize12: "12px",
  fontsize14: "14px",
  fontsize16: "16px"
}
var Constants = {
  OKWON: 100000000
}
let topRightOption = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 10,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    animation: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Unit',
    align: 'left',
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    },
    margin: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 12,
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [],
    crosshair: true,
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
        fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: ' '
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        },
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value / Constants.OKWON, 1);
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: {
        text: ' ',
        style: {}
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1);
        },
        style: {
          color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
          fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize12
        }
      },
      opposite: true,
      offset: 10,
      crosshair: true
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var tooltip = [],

        title = "<span class=\"TooltipText12\">" + this.x + "</span><br/>";
      tooltip.push(title + '<br>');
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        if (i < 2) {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y / Constants.OKWON, 1) + '<span style="padding:0"> 억원</span> <br/>');
        } else {
          tooltip.push("<span style=\"color:" + this.point.color + "\">●</span> " + this.series.name + ": " + this.point.y + '<span style="padding:0">%</span> <br/>');
        }

      });

      return tooltip.join('');
    },
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      groupPadding: 0.4,
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: {
      animation: false
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#fe7c7c', '#43d487', '#ff9600'],
  series: [],
  legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    itemStyle: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  }
};

data = {
  "StatisticGoalFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 900000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 700000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 770000000.0
    }
  ],
  "StatisticRealFee": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 860000000.0
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 460000000.0
    }, {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 590000000.0
    }
  ],
  "ProgressKRW100Rate": [{
      "Name": "(BOARD)",
      "Value": 0.5
    },
    {
      "Name": "(COMPONENT)",
      "Value": 117.9
    },
    {
      "Name": "(MODULE)",
      "Value": 3.0
    }
  ]
};



let seriesGoal = data.StatisticGoalFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let seriesReal = data.StatisticRealFee.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
let rates = data.ProgressKRW100Rate.map(c => ({
  name: c.Name,
  y: c.Value
}));
topRightOption.xAxis.categories = seriesGoal.map(c => c.name);

//this.bottomRightOption.series[1].data = seriesReal;
var top_right = Highcharts.chart('container', topRightOption);
top_right.addSeries({
  name: "도전",
  data: seriesGoal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      textOutline: false,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    },
    align: 'right',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});

top_right.addSeries({
  name: "실적",
  data: seriesReal,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    padding: 5,
    style: {
      color: ConstantsConfigChart.colorText,
      fontSize: ConstantsConfigChart.fontsize14,
      textOutline: false,
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    align: 'left',
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / Constants.OKWON, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: but our requirement is column with 35px

Comment: @HienNguyen I thought your requirement was to reduce the space between columns, not set the bar width?

Comment: our requirement both column with 35px and reduce space between column